# How to extract metadata including whole file content in sharepoint REST api

Tags: rest

Now, I want to extract file content using sharepoint REST api. My goal is: extract file metadata and entire file content (just pure content, no structures). After searching online, I notice I can use following three methods:

1.`http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'`

2.`https//SHAREPOINT_HTTPS_DOMAIN/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents/ChilkatTest/japanese.csv')/$value`

3.`https://SHAREPOINT_HTTPS_DOMAIN/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents/ChilkatTest/japanese.csv')`

But no matter what method, I cannot get file text content as I expected.

e.g For PDF or PPT file, there are lots of structures in them. But sharepoint could extract pure text content from PDF or PPT file. Now, I just wanna get those content.

So anyone could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the param `binaryStringResponseBody' => true` with (2)